# Changing Label based on SQL Server table data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, forms, label

I have a bunch of label text in a form.

I've manage to get 1 data from another form to this form.

But now I need to extract data from a table based on the data from the other form..

For a better understanding, see the picture below

The `cName` value is from another form and when I run the program, it will change to a company name (this is ok)

A picture : [image: Form]

This is my code for this form :

```
public partial class UserFullDetail : Form
{
        public UserFullDetail(string detail)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblcName.Text = detail;
        }

        private void UserFullDetail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection SCScon = new SqlConnection();
            SCScon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlDataAdapter daS = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cDetails, cDetails2 , mainCate , PhoneNumber, PersonCharge FROM ComDet where cName='" + lblcName.Text + "'", SCScon);
            SCScon.Open();
            DataTable dts3 = new DataTable();
            daS.Fill(dts3);
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is to change the `cDetails` and the other things, based on the `cName`.

In my coding I have setup a datatable and dataset, but I don't know how to extract it so that the label can use the data inside.

help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

- using a `using () { ... }` block for your `SqlConnection` to ensure proper disposal of those objects
- use **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection attacks

So change your code to be:

```
private void UserFullDetail_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

   DataTable dts3 = new DataTable();

   using (SqlConnection SCScon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
      string query = "SELECT cDetails, cDetails2, mainCate, PhoneNumber, PersonCharge FROM dbo.ComDet WHERE cName = @CName";

      SqlDataAdapter daS = new SqlDataAdapter(query, SCScon);
      daS.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = lblcName.Text;

      SCScon.Open();
      daS.Fill(dts3);
      SCScon.Close();
   }

   // get the first (and hopefully only) row from your DataTable
   DataRow firstRow = dts3.Rows[0];

   // fill the values to your labels
   lblFirstDetail.Text = firstRow["cDetails"].ToString();
   lblSecondDetail.Text = firstRow["cDetails2"].ToString();
   lblCategory.Text = firstRow["mainCate"].ToString();
   lblPhoneNumber.Text = firstRow["PhoneNumber"].ToString();
   lblPersonInCharge.Text = firstRow["PersonCharge"].ToString();
}
```

Of course, for your "real world" app, you'd have to add some checking and error handling (e.g. make sure the value in `firstRow["mainCate"]` isn't returning `NULL` - because in that case, calling `.ToString()` on it will cause an exception), but that's the basic mechanism of how your code should look like.

And also, from an architecture point of view - I would strongly recommend to put all your database access code into a separate assembly that handles all of this work - don't put all this code into all your code-behind classes!

Comment: i'll take a note.. thank you marc.. sorry about the previous action..

Answer (score 2):

In this way you can get the value of DataTable.

```
List<string> detail = new List<string>();
foreach( DataRow dr in dts3.Rows)
{
  detail.Add(dr["cDetails"].ToString());
}
lblcDetails = detail[0];
```

Comment: so to be specific , 

i can do the coding , for each of the details i need? like the phonenumber and the personscharge?

Comment: just write the column name in dr["columnname"] to get the value of the specific column.

Comment: what does the detail infront , after the string do? that's like a container of the data i need right?

Comment: now i edited it will work like a container. you will get the value of detail column of every row in your database

Comment: so then how do i put it into the label? 

is it lblcDetails = detail.cDetails ?

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.windows.forms.label'

Comment: shujaat? u there sir?

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin it's not about being jerk, but there are many tutorials about these basic things on the internet. there's no reason to ask here

Comment: hmm.. i am.. really new to this.. by the way , the code works after i changed lblcDetails to lblcDetails.Text